# fabric8io docker-maven-plugin in Windows

Tags: maven, docker, maven-plugin

I'm trying to do some integration test with maven, docker and Cassandra.

Right now, I have write a dummy code to query Cassandra and trying to maven run the Cassandra container.

This is the pom.xml about the plugin:

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.14.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <images>
                    <image>
                        <alias>some-cassandra</alias>
                        <name>cassandra:3.0</name>
                        <run>
                            <ports>
                                <!--<port>cassandra.port:9042</port>-->
                                <port>9042:9042</port>
                                <port>9160:9160</port>
                                <port>7199:7199</port>
                                <port>7001:7001</port>
                            </ports>
                            <wait>
                                <log>database system is ready to accept connections</log>
                                <time>30000</time>
                            </wait>
                        </run>
                    </image>
                </images>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <!-- "build" should be used to create the images with the
                             artifact -->
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When I try to run it, firstly I got an error about DOCKER_NAME is not available, I set an system variable with different names: "default", "localhost" and so on. 
I don't know really where I could check that name, I tried `docker-machine inspect` and it seems that the name is "default"

Finally, when I set the DOCKER_NAME (with a value which I don't know if it's right, but i guess not). I get an error from Maven

```
[INFO] --- docker-maven-plugin:0.14.1:start (start) @ integration ---
**[ERROR] DOCKER> Connect to localhost:2375 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
[ERROR] DOCKER> Error occurred during container startup, shutting down...**
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.595 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-12T16:31:55+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/312M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.14.1:start (start) on project integration: I/O Error: Unable to check image [cassandra:3.0] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Is someone using this pluging in Windows?

Comment: Did you do test your docker installation and see that at least 'hello world' worked?